# How to edit css live with ie6

Tags: css, edit, internet-explorer-6

Hallo all.
I need a tool similar to firebug with ie6 to edit css live.

I tried to use ie developer toolbar but in ie6 seems not to let you edit the DOM as wanted.
Is there any tool around?

Kind regards
Massimo Ugues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one but it's pretty buggy.
It's called cssVista.
I am using version 0.1.5.3.

Answer (score 1):

I've not checked to see if you can change or edit CSS live in it, but I've used [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)  in Internet Explorer in the past. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard great things about Adobe Dreamweaver CS 5, it has this feature. I also here that where other software has failed (things like Drupal with a bazillion nested CSS files), Dreamweaver CS 5 handles well.